# How to turn a string into a list in python?

Tags: python, string, list

```
l = "['Hello', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'Apple']"
l1 = ['Hello', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'Apple']
```

`type(l)` returns `str` but I want it to be a list, as `l1` is.

How can I transform that string into a common list?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

the `ast` module has a `literal_eval` that does what you want

```
import ast
l = "['Hello', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'Apple']"
l1 = ast.literal_eval(l)
```

Outputs:

```
['Hello', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'Apple']
```

[docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

Comment: Nice to see the first answer to this question being `literal_eval`, not the regular dangerous `eval`.

Comment: @sweeneyrod they should just rename `eval` to `evil`

Answer (score 0):

ast.literal_eval is a nice approach. For those preferint string manipulation, another option is:

```
l1 = [x[1:-1] for x in l[1:-1].split(', ')]
```